Rust - Syn and Quote
I am trying to learn how the syn and quote libraries work and basically how parsing and code gen are done.  So I wrote a simple macro to convert a Rust function to a .json schema. The macro is given below. It works well except for a case where we have the Where clause.



use proc_macro::{self, TokenStream};
use quote::{quote, format_ident};
use syn::{
    parse_macro_input, ItemFn, ReturnType, Attribute, parse::Parse, parse::ParseStream, FnArg, Generics, Visibility,
    LitStr, Lit,Expr, Meta, Result
};


// Custom attribute parser
struct MacroAttributes {
    description: Option<String>,
}

impl Parse for MacroAttributes {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        let description = if input.peek(LitStr) {
            let desc_lit = input.parse::<LitStr>()?;
            Some(desc_lit.value())
        } else {
            None
        };

        Ok(MacroAttributes { description })
    }
}

// Function to extract documentation comments from function attributes.
fn extract_doc_comments(attrs: &[Attribute]) -> Result<Option<String>> {
    let mut docs = Vec::new();
    for attr in attrs {
        match &attr.meta {
            Meta::NameValue(nv) if nv.path.is_ident("doc") => {
                if let Expr::Lit(expr_lit) = &nv.value {
                    if let Lit::Str(lit) = &expr_lit.lit {
                        docs.push(lit.value());
                    }
                }
            },
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    if docs.is_empty() {
        Ok(None)
    } else {
        Ok(Some(docs.join("\n")))
    }
}


// Function to generate JSON-like schema information for generics in a function.
fn process_generics(generics: &Generics) -> Option<proc_macro2::TokenStream> {
    let type_params: Vec<_> = generics.type_params().map(|param| {
        let ident = &param.ident;                       // Identifier of the type parameter.
        let bounds = param.bounds.iter().map(|b| quote! {#b}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
        quote! {
            {"name": stringify!(#ident), "bounds": [#(#bounds),*]}
        }
    }).collect();

    if type_params.is_empty() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(quote! { [#(#type_params),*] })
    }
}

// Similar function for where clauses.
fn process_where_clause(generics: &Generics) -> Option<proc_macro2::TokenStream> {
    let where_clauses: Vec<_> = generics.where_clause.as_ref().map_or(Vec::new(), |where_clause| {
        where_clause.predicates.iter().map(|predicate| {
            quote! { stringify!(#predicate) }
        }).collect()
    });

    if where_clauses.is_empty() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(quote! {
            "where_clauses": [#(#where_clauses),*]
        })
    }
}


// Similar function for lifetimes.
fn process_lifetimes(generics: &Generics) -> Option<proc_macro2::TokenStream> {
    let lifetimes: Vec<_> = generics.lifetimes().map(|lifetime| {
        let ident = &lifetime.lifetime.ident;
        quote! {stringify!(#ident)}
    }).collect();

    if lifetimes.is_empty() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(quote! { [#(#lifetimes),*] })
    }
}



// The `myschema` macro function that processes attributes and the function to which it is applied.
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn myschema(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let attrs = parse_macro_input!(attr as MacroAttributes);

    let input_fn = parse_macro_input!(item as ItemFn);
    let fn_name = &input_fn.sig.ident;
    let visibility_str = match &input_fn.vis {
        Visibility::Public(_) => "public",
        Visibility::Restricted(res) => if res.path.is_ident("crate") { "crate" } else { "restricted" },
        Visibility::Inherited => "private",
    };
    let generics = &input_fn.sig.generics;
    let generics_info = process_generics(&input_fn.sig.generics);
    let lifetimes_info = process_lifetimes(&input_fn.sig.generics);
    let where_info = process_where_clause(&input_fn.sig.generics);
    let return_type = match &input_fn.sig.output {
        ReturnType::Default => None,
        ReturnType::Type(_, t) => Some(quote! {#t}),
    };
    let is_async = input_fn.sig.asyncness.is_some();
    let doc_comments = match extract_doc_comments(&input_fn.attrs) {
        Ok(Some(docs)) => docs,
        Ok(None) => String::new(),
        Err(_) => return TokenStream::from(quote! { compile_error!("Error parsing doc comments"); })
    };

    // Generate the JSON-like schema for the function parameters.
    let inputs: Vec<_> = input_fn.sig.inputs.iter().map(|arg| {
        if let FnArg::Typed(pat_type) = arg {
            let pat = &pat_type.pat;
            let ty = &pat_type.ty;
            quote! {
                {
                    "name": stringify!(#pat),
                    "type": stringify!(#ty)
                }
            }
        } else {
            quote! {}
        }
    }).collect();

    let mut schema_fields = vec![
        quote! { "name": stringify!(#fn_name) },
        quote! { "visibility": #visibility_str },
        quote! { "documentation": #doc_comments },

    ];

    if let Some(desc) = attrs.description {
        schema_fields.push(quote! { "description": #desc });
    }

    if !inputs.is_empty() {
        schema_fields.push(quote! { "parameters": [#(#inputs),*] });
    }

    if let Some(rt) = return_type {
        schema_fields.push(quote! { "return_type": stringify!(#rt) });
    }

    if is_async {
        schema_fields.push(quote! { "is_async": true });
    }

    if let Some(generics) = generics_info {
        schema_fields.push(quote! { "generics": #generics });
    }


    if let Some(where_clause) = where_info {
        schema_fields.push(quote! { "where_clause": #where_clause });
    }

    if let Some(lifetimes) = lifetimes_info {
        schema_fields.push(quote! { "lifetimes": #lifetimes });
    }

    let schema_function_name = format_ident!("schema_{}", fn_name);

    let schema_fn = quote! {
        pub fn #schema_function_name() -> ::std::result::Result<String, serde_json::Error> {
            let schema = serde_json::json!({ #(#schema_fields),* });
            serde_json::to_string_pretty(&schema)
        }
    };

    let output = quote! {
        #input_fn
        #schema_fn
    };

    output.into()
}



My Test is shown below. Only the first case fails. What can I do?
use rust_macro::myschema; // Import the schema macro

// This fails
#[myschema("Generic multiplication")]
pub fn multiply<T>(x: T, y: T) -> T
where
    T: std::ops::Mul<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    x * y
}

/// My async function
#[myschema("Asynchronous fetch")]
pub async fn fetch_data(url: &str) -> Result<String, &'static str> {
    Ok("data".to_string())
}

#[myschema("Multiplies two numbers")]
pub fn multiply_doc(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    x * y
}


#[myschema("Determines the longest of two string slices")]
pub fn longest<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if x.len() > y.len() { x } else { y }
}

#[myschema("Private function")]
fn private_function() -> bool {
    true
}

fn main() {
    if let Ok(schema_output) = schema_multiply::<i32>() {
        println!("Generated schema: {}", schema_output);
    }

    if let Ok(schema_output) = schema_fetch_data() {
        println!("Generated schema: {}", schema_output);
    }

    if let Ok(schema_output) = schema_multiply_doc() {
        println!("Generated schema: {}", schema_output);
    }

    if let Ok(schema_output) = schema_longest() {
        println!("Generated schema: {}", schema_output);
    }

    if let Ok(schema_output) = schema_private_function() {
        println!("Generated schema: {}", schema_output);
    }
}


The error is:
/rust-macro-test)
error: no rules expected the token `:`
   --> src/main.rs:4:1
    |
4   | #[myschema("Generic multiplication")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
    |
note: while trying to match `,`
   --> /home/richard/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde_json-1.0.116/src/macros.rs:303:14
error[E0107]: function takes 0 generic arguments but 1 generic argument was supplied
  --> src/main.rs:34:32
   |
34 |     if let Ok(schema_output) = schema_multiply::<i32>() {
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------- help: remove these generics
   |                                |
   |                                expected 0 generic arguments
   |
note: function defined here, with 0 generic parameters
  --> src/main.rs:4:8
   |
4  | pub fn multiply<T>(x: T, y: T) -> T
   |        ^^^^^^^^


You forgot to add the generics to schema_fn.

any idea how I can do this?

Define the desired genericis and add them: #schema_function_name < #generics >

Here's what I did
 pub fn #schema_function_name #generics()  -> ::std::result::Result<String, serde_json::Error> #where_clause_tokens {
            let schema = serde_json::json!({ #(#schema_fields),* });
            serde_json::to_string_pretty(&schema)
        }


There is no variable generics in scope where you define schema_fn can you add it's definition? (did you maybe use generics_info instead?)

I 've updated the original question.

I also added a couple of enhancements that make it possible to generate the JSON at build time. I hope to make it into a small crate.

To fix this issue, you need to adjust your schema_multiply function so that it doesn't require any generic parameters when called. You have already done this correctly in your macro output, so the main change needed is in how you call schema_multiply in your main function.
if let Ok(schema_output) = schema_multiply() {
    println!("Generated schema: {}", schema_output);
}


I don't think its just that. I have updated the error. I get: #[myschema("Generic multiplication")]
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call

seems like an issue with the parsing.
